How to add namespace when add node to XML with xml.etree.ElementTree?
I have next code to parse one XML string, and then add a new node to the XML. But you can see my code can only add <category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_6.6" /> without namespace.
I need the ns0 before category.
test_xml.py:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

source_str = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:testcase xmlns:ns0="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/">
<ns0:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_5.4"/>
</ns0:testcase>
"""

xml_root = ET.fromstring(source_str)
new_str = '<category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_6.6"/>'
new_node = ET.fromstring(new_str)
xml_root.append(new_node)
final_str = ET.tostring(xml_root, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')

print(final_str)

Execution:
$ python3 test_xml.py
<ns0:testcase xmlns:ns0="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/">
<ns0:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_5.4" />
<category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_6.6" /></ns0:testcase>

My expectation:
<ns0:testcase xmlns:ns0="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/">
<ns0:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_5.4" />
<ns0:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_6.6" /></ns0:testcase>

If I change the code like this:
new_str = '<ns0:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_6.6"/>'
new_node = ET.fromstring(new_str)

It will just give me error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nxa13855/test_xml.py", line 11, in <module>
    new_node = ET.fromstring(new_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1347, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 1, column 0

How can I manage my aim?

I managed it with adding namespace & define xmlns when define string of new node:
new_str = '<ns0:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_6.6" xmlns:ns0="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/"/>'

With this, the code won't print error anymore, because it find the prefix mapping for ns0.
Execution:
$ python3 test_xml.py
<ns0:testcase xmlns:ns0="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/">
<ns0:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_5.4" />
<ns0:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_6.6" /></ns0:testcase>


You can use register_namespace(prefix, uri) .The prefix ns0 is a placeholder only. You should use qm instead, see IBM. See also Background python xml.etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

source_str = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:testcase xmlns:ns0="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/">
<ns0:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_5.4"/>
</ns0:testcase>
"""

xml_root = ET.fromstring(source_str)

ET.register_namespace("qm", "http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/")

new_cat= ET.Element("qm:category")
new_cat.set("term", "Platform Version")
new_cat.set("value", "Linux_6.6")

xml_root.append(new_cat)

# Pretty Print and write to file
tree = ET.ElementTree(xml_root)
ET.indent(tree, space="  ")
tree.write("test.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")

ET.dump(xml_root)

Output file:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<qm:testcase xmlns:qm="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/">
  <qm:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_5.4" />
  <qm:category term="Platform Version" value="Linux_6.6" />
</qm:testcase>

